# highcharts column animation when adding point (series.addPoint())

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

I would like to change/customize highcharts' animation when adding new point.

```
series.addPoint([x, y], true, false);
```

Here is an example of hightcharts' default animation : 
http://jsfiddle.net/pe4csrr7/
On click on a button (next or prev) you can see that the new bars appears behind the last one.

Instead of this default animation, I would like to see the bars coming from outside the graph. Here is an example of what I want : http://jsfiddle.net/smsducrg/   (Warning : the animations of this example is not always the same, after a while the default animation will come back, I don't know why...)

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, maybe instead of using chart.redraw() you can use xAxis.setExtremes() for redrawing your chart. I think that with small trick you will be able to achieve what you would like to. Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/pe4csrr7/2/

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. It helped me a lot.
But did you notice that when you clic up to ~50 times on the 'prev' button or on the 'next' button, the animation changes (after ~50 clic, the new bar don't come anymore from outside the graph).
Do you know why ? 
Thanks.

Comment: You can set cropThreshold to bigger value: http://jsfiddle.net/pe4csrr7/5/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using chart.redraw() you can use xAxis.setExtremes() for redrawing your chart. 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setExtremes

I think that with small trick you will be able to achieve what you would like to.

```
$(function() {
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
    },
    series: [{
      data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      cropThreshold:0
    }]
  });

  $('#prev').attr('start', 0);
  $('#next').attr('end', 6);

  $('#prev').off('click').on('click', function() {
    var next = parseInt($('#next').attr('end'), 10) - 1;
    var prev = parseInt($('#prev').attr('start'), 10) - 1;

    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].addPoint({
      x: prev,
      y: 1
    }, false, false);
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(prev + 1, next)
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(prev, next)

    $('#next').attr('end', next);
    $('#prev').attr('start', prev);
  });


  $('#next').off('click').on('click', function() {
    var next = parseInt($('#next').attr('end'), 10) + 1;
    var prev = parseInt($('#prev').attr('start'), 10) + 1;

    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].addPoint({
      x: next,
      y: 1
    }, false, true);
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(prev, next - 1)
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(prev, next)
    $('#next').attr('end', next);
    $('#prev').attr('start', prev);
  });
});
```

You need to add bigger cropThreshold than default if you want to have this animation also after many button clicks (so for example when you will add 50 points).

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/pe4csrr7/5/